# How do I check if a saved import exists with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Part of some vba code I'm writing calls a saved import using:

```
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "import_name"
```

This is working quite well for me, except when the saved import does not exist. In that case it fails silently.

Is there a way to check whether the import definition exists so that I can raise an error or take other action if it doesn't?

I'm using Access 2010 but it needs to work in 2003 as well.

Comment: It won't work in Access 2003.  `DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport` was added in Access 2007: [DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243760(v=office.12).aspx) "**Version Added:** Access 2007"

Comment: Ah, thanks. I wouldn't have known until testing...

Comment: Thanks for the thumbs up. I have posted a more general solution that I tested with Access 2002.

Comment: In the end an import specification wasn't really necessary so I went with 'DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet', which worked across versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide and error handler to resolve this issue (Access 2007 and higher):

```
Sub Importer()
On Error GoTo ErrImport

DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "import_name"

ExitImporter:
  Exit Sub

ErrImport:
  MsgBox Error 'Err = 31602 for missing import specification
  Resume ExitImporter

End Sub
```

A more general solution uses the TransferText command as follows:

```
Sub Importer()
    On Error GoTo ErrImport

DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Import_file Import Specification", "import_file", "import_file.txt", False

ExitImporter:
  Exit Sub

ErrImport:
    MsgBox "Error Number = " & Err & ", Message=" & Error ' Error 3011 indicates import_file.txt not found
    Resume ExitImporter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In Access 2003 they are stored in the hidden "MSysIMEXSpecs" system table, not sure if this remains in later versions but if so you can view it with standard SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM MSysIMEXSpecs
```

The column name is "SpecName" so this is probably more fitting:

```
SELECT * FROM MSysIMEXSpecs WHERE SpecName = 'Your Spec Name'
```

This would avoid having to trap error's